# Validate CSV File columns in php

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have three columns email,phoneno and address columns in csv file.I want to upload csv file.At the time of uploading ,I want to validate  csv file column name address.For example:- if address column is in csv file have no of addresses and their length is 200 or 300.If address column size is 100 which is mentioned  in database if someone exceeds the size of address column in csv file then it gives alert to users that the address field is exceedes its limit.
This code is for csv file upload.At the time of upload it checks the csv file column from database.those columns which are match with database show a dropdown with selected columns otherwise there is a dropdown shown with add a field option.

```
<?php 

   require 'db.php';
// $mimes = array('text/csv');
// if(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$mimes)){
  // do something

 if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 


$columnnames='';
$i=0;
$numcolumn='';
$show= '';
$numcolumn1='';
 $columnnames1='';
$j=0;

$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
// if($file["extension"] != "csv")
//   {
//     echo "Please select CSV file";
//     //header("location:ind1.php");
//     exit;
//   }
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($file);
// $target_file = $target_dir . basename($file);
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 


$store=$_FILES["csv"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($file, "uploads/" . $store);
            //echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $store . "<br />";
$csv_fields = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'); 


$arr12=array();
$after = array();
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM user";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$arr12[]=$row['Field'];


}

foreach($arr12 as $v){
    $after[] = implode(' ', array_map('ucfirst', explode('_', $v)));
    // $after1= explode($after);

}
$af=implode(',' , $after);

// /echo $af;

//print_r($after);
//print_r($arr);
$tbl_fields=array_slice($arr12, 1);
$array1 = $csv_fields;
$array2 = $tbl_fields; 

//$c=implode(" ",$array1);
//print_r($c);
//print_r($array2);
$words1 =  array_unique($array1);
//print_r($words1)."<br>";

$words2 =  array_unique($array2);
//print_r($words2)."<br>";
$default=array();
// if (count($array1)>$array2){
//        $error=true;

//    }
$intersection = array_intersect($words1, $words2);

 $intersection1 = array_diff($words1, $words2);

$merge= array_merge($intersection, $intersection1);

usort($merge, function($a, $b) use ($words1){
   // sort using the numeric index of the second array
   $valA = array_search($a, $words1);
   $valB = array_search($b, $words1);

   // move items that don't match to end
   if ($valA === false)
       return -1;
   if ($valB === false)
       return 0;

   if ($valA > $valB)
       return 1;
   if ($valA < $valB)
       return -1;
   return 0;
});
//print_r($merge);
$row = 1;
$f = $handle;


//$tbl_fields = array('first_name','last_name','email');
if ($handle !== FALSE) {

  //if($csv_fields !== FALSE) {
        echo '<div class="container panel" style="background:#F5F7FA;margin-top:30px;">
        <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-5" style="float:left;">

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn"></span>';

   echo "<div style='color:red;'>Please check the column headers below to confirm we've labeled them correctly.</div>";

// foreach($merge as $a)
// {
foreach($merge as $a)
{
  if(in_array($a,$array2)){

    // if($columnnames == $a){
       echo "<div class='form-group'><table>"; 

echo "<tr>

 <td><input  type='text' value='".$a."'  class='textbox  form-control' id='textbox'></td>
<td><input  type='hidden' value='".$a."'  class='textbox2  form-control' id='textbox2'></td>

<td><input type='hidden' id='newhiddenBox' class='newhiddenBox' value='".$a."'></td>


<br>"; 

 echo "</tr></table></div>";
 }


else{
  echo "<div class='form-group'><table><tr><td>"; 



    echo "

    <td><input  type='text' value='".$a."'  class='textbox tt form-control' id='textbox'></td>

    <td><input  type='hidden' value='".$a."'  class='textbox1 form-control' id='textbox1'></td>
<td><input type='hidden' id='newhiddenBox'class='newhiddenBox' value='".$a."'></td>  



</tr></table></div>";
}
}

  echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-md-7' style='float:left;'>
        <h3>database headers</h3>";
 foreach($merge as $a)
{
  if(in_array($a,$array2)){

    // if($columnnames == $a){
       echo "<div class='form-group'><table>"; 

echo "<tr><td>
<select name='drop[]' class='select_drop textbox textbox1 form-control' id='select_drop' style='width:200px;'>"; 

         echo "<option  value='".$a."'>$a</option>";

         echo "<optgroup label='database headers'>"; 

         $res = mysql_query('select * from user');
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($res);

for ( $i = 1; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
            $columnnames = mysql_field_name($res, $i);

            echo '<option value="'.$columnnames.'" class="d ">'.$columnnames.'</option>';

    // $after1= explode($after);



          } 

         echo "</optgroup></td>";

echo "
<td><input  type='hidden' value='".$a."'  class='textbox2  form-control' id='textbox2'></td>

<td><input type='hidden' id='newhiddenBox' class='newhiddenBox' value='".$a."'></td>
 <td><input type='checkbox'  name='check' value='".$a."' class='check checkbox-primary' >Add Column</td> 

<br>"; 

 echo "</select></tr></table></div>";
 }


else{
  echo "<div class='form-group'><table><tr><td><select name='drop[]' class='drop  textbox  hiddentxtbox form-control' >"; 



        echo "<optgroup selected label='newtextfields'>
        <option value=''>Add Field or Choose</option>
         <option value='text'>Add new Field</option>

         </optgroup>
         <optgroup label='database headers' class='hd'>"; 

         $res = mysql_query('select * from user');
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($res);
for ( $i = 1; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {

            $columnnames = mysql_field_name($res, $i);
            echo '<option value="'.$columnnames.'" >'.$columnnames.'</option>';

          } 
         echo "</optgroup>";

     echo "</select></td>";

    echo "


    <td><input  type='hidden' value='".$a."'  class='textbox1 form-control' id='textbox1'></td>
<td><input type='hidden' id='newhiddenBox'class='newhiddenBox' value='".$a."'></td>  


<td><input type='checkbox' name='check'  value='".$a."' class='check checkbox-primary' style='margin-left:5px;'>Add Column</td>

</tr></table></div>";
}
}
       echo  "</div>
        </div>

       <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='submit' class='col-md-2 btn btn-md btn btn-primary '>

       </div>
        ";


    fclose($handle);

 // }

  }

//}

}
// else{
//   $show="please select a file";
//  }
}


?>
```

Comment: I have a lot of code for upload a csv file in php so  show all the code is not possible here.

Comment: I mean this the in the most polite way possible - then finding help is not possible here

Comment: ok let me edit the question